# Why are alpha-carbonyl relatively less stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, halides

So if we have an alpha halogen ketone, why is an Sn1 type mechanism so unfavorable for that species?

I don't understand. It seems like the C+ would be resonance stabilized by the carbonyl's double bond.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Would you mind to explain how a carbocation next to an electrophilic centre is stabilized by resonance?

Comment: Could you push the pi electrons in the carbonyl to form an alkene from the alpha carbon to the carbonyl carbon and a + charged oxygen?

Comment: A plus charge on oxygen is highly unfavourable situation even more worse than carbocation

Answer (score 3):

The carbon atom of the carbonyl group has a partial positive charge due to electron withdrawal by the electronegative oxygen atom. An $S_{N}1$ mechanism would result in an intermediate with a positive charge next to a partial positive charge, which would be high in energy.